# Recovery Services Vault can't find subscription

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

I'm using Terraform to deploy, via Azure Pipelines, a handful of resources to Azure Gov. It's worked with other deployments and the code hasn't changed in months.

It creates the resource, but still throws the following error.

> updating Recovery Service Storage Cfg Vault: (Name "myRSV" / Resource
> Group "myRGP"): backup.ResourceStorageConfigsClient#Update: Failure
> responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error:
> autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404
> Code="SubscriptionNotFound" Message="The subscription
> 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' could not be found."
>
> with
> module.tenant-module.azurerm_recovery_services_vault.tenant-rsv[0],
>
> on ....\modules\tenant\key-vault.tf line 124, in resource
> "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "tenant-rsv":
>
> 124: resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "tenant-rsv" {

Some additional notes:

- The subscription in question is the one it's deploying to. It
  obviously exists.
- I saw an issue on the azurerm provider repo that referenced this, but
  I'm not running on the version that issue was. I'm using 2.89.0.
- The service principal that this is running as has Contributor access
  to the subscription.

Any ideas?

Comment: hello @SPSaml, can you please share the code you are running? so that i can test it out?

Comment: Hi, will it throw the error for each pipeline run? And if possible, please move the in-private data and share the pipeline definition.

Comment: So, the issue wasn't Azure at all.  I've been using >=2.89.0 for the azurerm Terraform provider.  2.90.0 or 2.91.0 broke it.  Going to file a bug today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error wasn't an Azure issue.  I was using the following provider:

```
azurerm = {
  source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
  version = ">=2.89.0"
}
```

I thought it was "=2.89.0."  I had done deployments early last week (1/10/22-1/12/22) without issues, but 2.91.0 released on 1/13/22 which introduced the issue.  Once I updated the version to "=2.90.0" it provisioned successfully.